# how to run two async operation in one step in node.js as one atomic operation?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have function which call two async functions. The main function handle requests from the users. Here is example:

```
mainFunction(req, res, done) {
   asyncExist(req, function(exists) {
       if (!exists) {
           asyncCreate(req, done);
       }
   })
}
```

The problem is when I have many requests. My main function is call async. Nodejs executes function asyncExist for many request before call function asyncCreate. In result asyncCreate function is call many times with the same parameters. Question is what to do with that fundamental problem?

Comment: I don't see the problem. The functions always will be called with the correct parameters once.

Comment: Please take to a count that I'm talking about multi requests.

Comment: node.js is single threaded, so data does not mixed up. One request per time is handled, the context is switched whenever a callback occurs or "comes back".

Comment: Example case. **UserA** make request and node.js call function 'mainFunction' and that function call 'asyncExist'. In that moment **UserB** make request and node.js execute function 'mainFunction' and that function call the same 'asyncExist'. Node.js get response from 'asyncExist' for **UserA** and out method call function 'asyncCreate'. Node.js get response from 'asyncExist' for **UserB** and call 'asyncCreate' for **UserB** too. In this case 'asyncCreate' for **UserA** is not finish so 'asyncExist' for **UserB** will return the same result like for **UserA**. This is not correct for my case.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but if you are worried stuff between UserA and UserB should get mixed up or order will not be maintained. Don't worry, node.js will handle that. That's exactly why node.js was created.

Comment: @TheHippo how is it handled? I'm very interested to know.

Answer (score 1):

You need a locking mechanism.  I'm not sure what datastore you're using, but you need to figure out what kind of locking or transaction primitives it provides.

A lock on the datastore allows you to allow the first request make subsequent requests wait before they begin with `asyncExist` until the first request has completely finished.

I've used a [lock pattern for redis](https://npmjs.org/package/redis-lock) that looked like this:

```
mainFunction(req, res, done) {
  asyncGetLock(function(releaseLock) {
    asyncExist(req, function(exists) {
      if(exists) {
        releaseLock();
        return;
      }
      asyncCreate(req, done, function() {
        releaseLock();
      });
    });
  });
}
```

Similar concept applies if you're using other datastores.  For instance, in SQL it would be called a transaction.  Your first request would be `begin transaction` then you would do your test and your conditional update and then you would `commit` or `rollback` as the final step.

Comment: This can be solution for me. I'm using mongodb. Question how to use lock for this DB?

Answer (score 0):

You might investigate using promises (like [when](https://github.com/cujojs/when)) if you're needing to do something after several async calls complete.

See http://blog.jcoglan.com/2013/03/30/callbacks-are-imperative-promises-are-functional-nodes-biggest-missed-opportunity/ for more info on promises...

Comment: This is something what not solve a problem. Similar things are in async library or step but this is not solution.